# PDO Event Constants

Tags: php, events, pdo, triggers

i've a little doubt about on PHP with PDO constants.
How i use it? There is no documentation and no example and no questions here about it.

Did some one put this into work knows how to use it?

```
PDO::PARAM_EVT_FREE (integer)

 Deallocation event

PDO::PARAM_EVT_EXEC_PRE (integer)

 Event triggered prior to execution of a prepared statement.

PDO::PARAM_EVT_EXEC_POST (integer)

 Event triggered subsequent to execution of a prepared statement.

PDO::PARAM_EVT_FETCH_PRE (integer)

 Event triggered prior to fetching a result from a resultset.

PDO::PARAM_EVT_FETCH_POST (integer)

 Event triggered subsequent to fetching a result from a resultset.

PDO::PARAM_EVT_NORMALIZE (integer)

 Event triggered during bound parameter registration allowing the driver to normalize the parameter name.
```

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These constants have no use in PHP code, and I don't really think they will be of much use any time soon. [As you can see here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/28b7a033185478839c511551ce2344e459e7f880/ext/pdo_mysql/mysql_statement.c#L453) They are part of the internal PDO api. Event hooks are used internally to distinguish between drivers: allocating a prepared statement, and its bound values happens requires different approaches on different drivers. (notice the `#if PDO_USE_MYSQLND` and `#else` macro's)

Perhaps they were added as class constants to enable users to pass in callbacks for these events if they so wish. If this is so, I don't think this is considered to be top priority for the PDO developers, though... 
Bottom line: ***You can't use them, simply ignore them***

Comment: Lines 597-603 says exactly what you say. '// do nothing'

Thank you.